# How do I get a full page background in IE8?

Tags: css, html, background

How do I get a full page background in IE8? it works fine in firefox and chrome. I specified the background of a 1000px div. But I am open to specifying the background of the body or html. Thanks for your time. Steven

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
html { 

}

div.whole{width="1000px";margin:0 auto;border-style:solid; border-width:0px;height:100%;padding:0px;

background: url(images/parchment.png) no-repeat center center  fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

}

html, body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 0px;
 height:100%;
width:100%
}

div.image{position:relative; top:50px;left:900px;width:300px; border-style:solid;border-width:0px;}



@font-face
{
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url(pachs___.ttf);
}

div.text{position:relative;left:250px;top:-300px; font-family:myFirstFont; font-size:250%;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;
width:600px;}


</style>

<body>
<div class="whole">

    <div class="image">
    <img src="images/tran.png" width="282px" height="381px" class="tran">
    </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

div.whole needs to go below the html, body tags. You aren't structuring it properly because the elements that appear first act as a container for the elements that appear second. This is a habit you need to get into even with css. You also need to specify the height, and I would recommend using percentage values to ensure it covers 100%. Just replace 1000px with 100%. If you want backgrounds for the html and body, you need to specify that within their own brackets.